# Phonegap build iOS GCM Registered but not receiving notification?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-build

[for ios GCM registered but not receive notification its display invalid credential why? we already uploaded updated .p12 ssl certificate and its expires on Nov 2018.so why it is give an error "InvalidApnsCredential".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fdfk.jpg)

- I'm using Phonegap Build on my project.
- This is my config file plugin code.[plugin for receive notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp2xa.jpg)
- This is my index.html file code.
  [for register GCM token id and receive notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VskLn.jpg)
- This is my php file code.[php script for call GCM api and get JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsBjv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1904), maybe you are registering with GCM and trying to send via APNS. You must create an iOS app in your GCM project. Create APNS certificates in Apple developer console and upload .p12 certificate files to GCM.

Here's another references:

- https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/292
- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1946

Comment: We have already create APNS .p12 certificates and uploaded into GCM. But we face same issue that is "InvalidApnsCredential" why? and we have also check my certificate validity but they have not expired.So, Please suggest Best way to resolve my this issue and follow up me as soon as possible.